# C++ char** -> vector<string> -> string -> char** parsing problem

Tags: c++, boost

Lets say that I'm trying to solve a parsing problem of string to char **
For some reason the below code generates a lot of trash, can anyone have a look at it please?

1. Here's what it's supposed to do :
2. Dump all argv into a string_array
   container
3. Dump everything in the string_array
   container into a std::string and
   separate with spaces
4. Break the string down into string
   tokens using boost/algorithm/string
5. create a new char ** and dump all
   tokens into it, print out the new char **, clean up

What have I done wrong ?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

typedef vector<string> string_array;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    string_array args;
    string_array tokens;
    cout << "Real arguments :" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    { cout << argv[i] << endl;}

    string arg = "";
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        args.push_back(argv[i]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)args.size(); i++)
    {
        arg += args[i];
        if(i != (int)args.size() - 1)
            arg += " ";
    }

    split(tokens, arg, is_any_of(" "));

    char ** new_args = NULL;
    new_args = new char*[(int)tokens.size()];
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)tokens.size(); i++)
    { 
        new_args[i] = new char[(int)tokens[i].size()];
        for(int j = 0; j < (int)tokens[i].size(); j++)
        {
            new_args[i][j] = tokens[i][j];
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < (int)tokens.size(); i++)
    { std::cout << new_args[i] << std::endl; }
    delete [] new_args;
}
```

Comment: Where and how does it go wrong?

Comment: Also, memory release of new_args is not correct. in a loop you also have to delete new_args[i]

Comment: @aJ: Mostly correct, but also have to use the array form of delete for deleting `new_args[i]`. :-)

Comment: Yes. Let me write it clearly :) delete [] new_args[i];

Comment: hmmm thought delete [] new_args would suffice, cheers guys

Comment: the forementioned delete [] new_args[i] is giving me HEAP_CORRUPTION_ERROR(s) - any hints on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C-style strings (`char*`) are meant to be zero-terminated. So instead of `new char[tokens[i].size()]`, you need to add 1 to the allocation: `new char[token[i].size() + 1]`. Also, you need to set `new_args[i][tokens[i].size()] = 0` to zero-terminate the string.

Without the zero-terminator, programs would not know when to stop printing, as `char*` does not hold a string length, unlike `std::string`.

Comment: Technically, that should be "null-terminated" lest someone start terminating their strings with '0' rather than '\0'.

Comment: Well, zero means `(char) 0`, not `'0'`. But I hear what you're saying. I don't like using "null-terminated" because it causes people to mix up NULL (pointer) and NUL (the character), and start writing NULL instead of 0 when they meant NUL, which is seriously uncool in my opinion. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: @Chris: I write NUL-terminated for strings and NULL-terminated for pointer arrays. I'm never sure whether anyone ever notices the difference, though...